# Проблема с автоматической сборкой в AppVeyoor .NET 4.8

Tags: .net, непрерывная-интеграция, ci-cd, .net-4.8, appveyor

Пытаюсь настроить автосборку в AppVeyour, но происходит проблема, судя по логам - не находит путь к Nuget. Пакеты на локальной машине nuget лежат на уровне солюшена:
Примерная структура каталога

> D:\Programming\Development\TinyMonitor\
>
> - packages (тут Nuget-пакеты)
> - TinyMonitorApp (тут находиться TinyMonitorApp)
> - TinyMonitor.sln

На локальной машине в VS 2022 все собирается на ура, ошибок нет.
Не знаю как решить данную проблему.
Вот ссылка на билд - [TinyMonitor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/Ledrunning/tinnymonitor-lu1w9)

И собственно сам скрипт :

```
image: Visual Studio 2022
configuration: Release
environment:
    major_version: 1
    minor_version: 7
    patch_version: 0
version: '$(major_version).$(minor_version).$(patch_version).{build}'
dotnet_csproj:
    patch: true
    file: 'TinyMonitorApp\TinyMonitorApp.csproj'
    package_version: '$(major_version).$(minor_version).$(patch_version)'
    assembly_version: '{version}'
    file_version: '{version}'
    informational_version: '{version}'

before_build: 
    # Display .NET version
    - cmd: dotnet --version
    # Display minimal restore text
    - cmd: dotnet restore
build_script:
    - cmd: dotnet build -c Release
artifacts:
- path: 'TinyMonitorApp\bin\Release\TinyMonitorApp.exe
name: Nuget
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема невнимательности. Так как проект был старый, я забыл, что пакеты загрузил онлайн и вытащил их как библиотеки в отдельную папку и уже потом подключал как .dll в референсы. Запушил папку с пакетами (там не много). В итоге билд собрался.
Решения два, тут либо пушить, либо переделать на онлайн нюгеты и ресторить в CI.
Т.е проблема в пути к пакетам